# SQL Server: How to open .PRC files?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssms

I have old .prc files (SQL Server Stored Procedures) which have exported from SQL Server 2000. Now when I try to open a .prc file using SSMS 2008, I get a bunch of chinese characters and other odd characters. I tried a solution found [here](http://www.eggheadcafe.com/forumarchives/SQLServerprogramming/Jan2006/post25608978.asp), but it did not help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you open the files in a regular text editor, e.g. Notepad or something??

As far as I remember, the SQL Server 2000 tools used to use ANSI / ISO-8869-1 encoding for their files, while newer Mgmt Studio version expect UTF-8 or UTF-16.

So my suggestion would be to open those *.PRC files in an editor and store them as *.SQL files using UTF-8 encoding. After that you should be able to open them in SSMS 2008 without problems.

Comment: Thanks, I converted to UTF-8 and thses chinese characters converted to "?". Now I can find-replace those from the file. Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Once I'd added PRC and UDF suffixes, ssms still ignored the changes if I used "recent files" to re-open the file was I working on.

I had to use File->Open to pick up the new suffixes. Thereafter "recent files" worked.